# 18.04: Duplicity stopped working

Tags: backup, deja-dup, duplicity

after reading related threads I realized, how brittle duplicity is for backups. Anyway, for some strange reasons deja-dup stopped working:

- first I got an error similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057627/duplicity-fails-with-bad-session-key-error) (probably made some small change to keyring / seahorse / gpg before, but I cannot remember exactly
- I then apt-get removed deja-dup and duplicity and
- snap installed latest version of both

Now I'm stuck with a new "known" error:

[Backup keeps asking for Encryption Password while restoring](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113139/backup-keeps-asking-for-encryption-password-while-restoring?rq=1)

which nobody (including me) was really able to recover from.

Here is the command line output when I start the 'snap'-ed deja-dup from command line using

```
export DEJA_DUP_DEBUG=1  
deja-dup  --backup
```

here is the error message:

```
UPLICITY: . Found primary backup chain with matching signature chain:
DUPLICITY: . -------------------------
DUPLICITY: . Chain start time: Thu May 27 11:42:53 2021
DUPLICITY: . Chain end time: Thu Jun 24 13:00:50 2021
DUPLICITY: . Number of contained backup sets: 5
DUPLICITY: . Total number of contained volumes: 1933
DUPLICITY: .  Type of backup set:                            Time:      Num volumes:
DUPLICITY: .                 Full         Thu May 27 11:42:53 2021              1817
DUPLICITY: .          Incremental         Wed Jun  2 17:49:47 2021                 3
DUPLICITY: .          Incremental         Thu Jun  3 03:32:43 2021                 2
DUPLICITY: .          Incremental         Thu Jun 24 12:04:03 2021               110
DUPLICITY: .          Incremental         Thu Jun 24 13:00:50 2021                 1
DUPLICITY: . -------------------------
DUPLICITY: . No orphaned or incomplete backup sets found.

DUPLICITY: INFO 1
DUPLICITY: . PASSPHRASE variable not set, asking user.

DUPLICITY: DEBUG 1
DUPLICITY: . Releasing lockfile b'/home/myUsername/snap/deja-dup/common/.cache/deja-dup/e9d3b7f870b518ba61d7edb618232bb5/lockfile'

DUPLICITY: DEBUG 1
DUPLICITY: . Removing still remembered temporary file /home/myUsername/snap/deja-dup/common/.cache/deja-dup/tmp/duplicity-fyu_uk0c-tempdir/mkstemp-slki6otd-1

DUPLICITY: DEBUG 1
DUPLICITY: . Releasing lockfile b'/home/myUsername/snap/deja-dup/common/.cache/deja-dup/e9d3b7f870b518ba61d7edb618232bb5/lockfile'

DUPLICITY: ERROR 30 EOFError
DUPLICITY: . Traceback (innermost last):
DUPLICITY: .   File "/snap/deja-dup/427/bin/duplicity", line 117, in <module>
DUPLICITY: .     with_tempdir(main)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/snap/deja-dup/427/bin/duplicity", line 103, in with_tempdir
DUPLICITY: .     fn()
DUPLICITY: .   File "/snap/deja-dup/427/lib/python3.8/site-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 1535, in main
DUPLICITY: .     do_backup(action)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/snap/deja-dup/427/lib/python3.8/site-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 1610, in do_backup
DUPLICITY: .     config.gpg_profile.passphrase = get_passphrase(1, action)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/snap/deja-dup/427/lib/python3.8/site-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 177, in get_passphrase
DUPLICITY: .     pass1 = getpass_safe(_(u"GnuPG passphrase:") + u" ")
DUPLICITY: .   File "/snap/deja-dup/427/lib/python3.8/site-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 74, in getpass_safe
DUPLICITY: .     return getpass.getpass(message)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/snap/deja-dup/427/usr/lib/python3.8/getpass.py", line 91, in unix_getpass
DUPLICITY: .     passwd = fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/snap/deja-dup/427/usr/lib/python3.8/getpass.py", line 126, in fallback_getpass
DUPLICITY: .     return _raw_input(prompt, stream)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/snap/deja-dup/427/usr/lib/python3.8/getpass.py", line 148, in _raw_input
DUPLICITY: .     raise EOFError
DUPLICITY: .  EOFError
DUPLICITY: .
```

my current snap versions are:

deja-dup 42.7
duplicity 0.8.19

Comment: first thing i'd do is trying to do the same in duplicity w/o DejaDup, just to make sure it is the duplicity bug. if so i'd file an issue at https://gitlab.com/duplicity/duplicity/-/issues

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I had used different passwords for backups and duplicity did not warn me when doing so. So in order to fix it I had to delete files with the different password in use.
It's explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1352750/380330)